# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: oledb, oledbconnection

I Have Windows 11. I'm Working In Visual Studio 2019 and try open and get data from Excel (I have Office 2019 Pro)

I Use this OleDB Connection Strings:

- `provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source ='" + Path + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;`

And

- `provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source ='" + Path + "'; Extended Properties=Excel 16.0 Xml;`

> And More String, But in vain.

### I Also Install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable.

I Have Windows 64 Bit and Office 64

> `Error: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' provider is not registered on the local machine`

Please help me how to solve this problem or suggest another way Without IronXL.